# haskell Either and Validation Applicative

Tags: haskell, applicative

I have a question arising from the section "Either and Validation Applicative" of Chapter 17 "Applicative" of the book "Haskell Programming from first principles".

I did the following code:

```
data Validation err a =
  Failure err
  | Success a
  deriving (Eq, Show)
data Errors =
  DividedByZero
  | StackOverflow
  | MooglesChewedWires
  deriving (Eq, Show)
instance Functor (Validation e) where
  fmap _ (Failure x) = Failure x
  fmap f (Success y) = Success (f y)
instance Monoid e =>
  Applicative (Validation e) where
    pure = Success
    Failure e1 <*> Failure e2
      = Failure (e1 <> e2)
    Failure e <*> _ = Failure e
    _ <*> Failure e = Failure e
    Success f <*> Success r = Success (f r)
success :: Validation [Errors] Int
success = Success (+1)
  <*> Success (1::Int)
fail0 :: Validation [Errors] Int
fail0 = Success (+1)
  <*> Failure [StackOverflow::Errors]
-- this doesn't work:
fail1a :: Validation [Errors] Int
fail1a = Failure [StackOverflow::Errors]
  <*> Success (1)
-- this works:
fail1b :: Validation [Errors] b
fail1b = Failure [StackOverflow::Errors]
  <*> Success (1::Int)
fail2 :: Validation [Errors] Int
fail2 = Failure [MooglesChewedWires]
  <*> Failure [StackOverflow::Errors]
fail3 :: Validation [Errors] Int
fail3 = (Failure [StackOverflow::Errors]
  <*> Success (+1)) <*> (Failure [MooglesChewedWires]
  <*> Failure [StackOverflow::Errors])
fail4 :: Validation [Errors] Int
fail4 = fail1b <*> fail2
```

`fail4 = fail1b <*> fail2` works, but if I changed it to:

`fail4 = fail1a <*> fail2`

An error is thrown:

```
Couldn't match type ‘Int’ with ‘Int -> Int’
  Expected type: Validation [Errors] (Int -> Int)
    Actual type: Validation [Errors] Int
• In the first argument of ‘(<*>)’, namely ‘fail1a’
  In the expression: fail1a <*> fail2
```

Why does this happen?  The only difference that `fail1a` has compared with `fail1b`, is the inclusion of type `Int` in its type signature instead of `b` ..

Comment: Well... don't you think `Int` and `b` are very different beasts? `b` can be anything, even `Int -> Int`, while `Int` can't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because `<*>` has type `Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`.

Let's look at definition of `fail4`:

```hs
fail4 :: Validation [Errors] Int
fail4 = fail1b <*> fail2
```

We can deduce expected types of `fail1b` and `fail2`:

```hs
fail4 :: Validation [Errors] Int
fail4 =       fail1b          <*>          fail2
              +----+                       +---+
                 v                           v
expected:   f (a -> b)                      f a       (Applicative f)
                 v                           v
real:   Validation [Errors] b      Validation [Errors] Int
                 v
   Validation [Errors] (Int -> c)
                 v
  Validation [Errors] (Int -> Int)
```

So, in this case type `Validation [Errors] b` of `fail1b` turn to `Validation [Errors] (Int -> Int)`.

However if you replace `fail1b` to `fail1a` it can't be done:

```hs
fail4 :: Validation [Errors] Int
fail4 =       fail1a          <*>          fail2
              +----+                       +---+
                 v                           v
expected:   f (a -> b)                      f a       (Applicative f)
              (error)                        v
real: Validation [Errors] Int      Validation [Errors] Int
```

You can fix it if you replace operator `<*>` to `*>`:

```hs
fail4 :: Validation [Errors] Int
fail4 = fail1b *> fail2 -- or fail1a *> fail2
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand that `Validation [Errors] b` becomes `Validation [Errors] (Int -> c)` because the `a` of `f (a -> b)` becomes the `Int` in `f a`, which should be `f Int`.  Is my understanding correct?

Comment: If my previous understanding is correct, then the `c` in `Validation [Errors] (Int -> c)` is actually the `b` in `f (a -> b)`.  `c` becomes `Int` in `Validation [Errors] (Int -> Int)` because of the `Int` in the type signature `fail4 :: Validation [Errors] Int`.  This `Int` is also the `Int` in the `f b` of `f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`, so the outcome is `f (Int -> Int) -> f Int -> f Int`.

Comment: Ok, could you explain more about how `*>` works?  I've tried `fail6 = fail2 *> success`, which works, but at https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-42--62-, it is stated that `*>` sequence actions, discarding the value of the first argument..

Comment: I've created a new discussion about this at:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67090168/haskell-sequencing-operator.