# haskell *> sequencing operator

Tags: haskell, sequencing

I have a question arising from the answer to my question at:
[haskell Either and Validation Applicative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67076356/haskell-either-and-validation-applicative)

My code is posted there.

It concerns the use of the `*>` sequencing operator instead of the `<*>` applicative operator.

Based on the explanation at https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-42--62-, I understand that `*>` sequences actions, discarding the value of the first argument.  So for my code, I've tried `fail6 = fail2 *> success`, which works, but it's not supposed to work because the value of the first argument, namely fail2, should be discarded.  Why does `fail6` work?

The output of `fail6` is `Failure [MooglesChewedWires,StackOverflow]`.

Comment: The value yes, but for an `Either`, that thus means a `Right x` will be discarded. If `fail2` results in a `Left y`, then that will be the result.

Comment: So if `fail2` fails, then that will be the result of `fail6`: the error that occurs.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, thanks, do you mean that the value of the first argument in this case is actually the value of `success`, which is the equivalent of the `Right` of an `Either`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With "discard the result", it means the result of an applicative. So for an `Either` that means a `Right y`. `(*>)` is thus equivalent to:

```
(*>) :: Applicative f => f a -> f b -> f b
(*>) f g = liftA2 (const id) f g
```

or in another form:

```
(*>) :: Applicative f => f a -> f b -> f b
(*>) f g = (const id) <$> f <*> g
```

It thus runs the two actions and returns the second result, but this in the "`Applicative` context".

For example for an `Either`, this is implemented as:

> ```
> instance Applicative (Either a) where
>     pure = Right
>     Left e <*> _ = Left e
>     _ <*> Left e = Left e
>     Right f <*> Right x = Right (f x)
> ```

This thus means that `(*>)` is implemented for an `Either` as:

```
-- (*>) for Either
(*>) :: Either a b -> Either a c -> Either a c
Left x *> _ = Left x
_ *> Left x = Left x
Right _ *> Right x = Right x
```

or equivalent:

```
-- (*>) for Either
(*>) :: Either a b -> Either a c -> Either a c
Left x *> _ = Left x
_ *> x = x
```

If the first operand is thus a `Right …`, it will return the second operand, if the first operand is `Left x`, it will return `Left x`.

Answer (score 3):

"Result" is quite a vague term, isn't it? When we talk about `Functor`, `Applicative` and `Monad`, we tend to refer to zero or more values in some sort of "context". So

- `IO a`: an I/O computation *producing* a value of type `a`.
- `[a]`: a list of zero or more values of type `a`.
- `Maybe a`: zero or one elements of type `a`.
- `Either e a`: just like `Maybe a` except that the no `a`s case is "decorated" with something of type `e`.
- `(x, a)`: a value of type `a` "decorated" with one of type `x`.
- `Identity a`: a value of type `a` without any context.

When you "discard the result", that means that you care about the *context* but not about the *value*. So:

- What did the I/O *do*?
- How many elements does the list have?
- Was the value `Just` something or `Nothing`?
- Was the value `Right` something or `Left e`?
- What was the decoration?
- No information.